# Handle same events from different windows

Tags: wpf, event-handling

I have a WPF project with two windows, the first window firing events and have it's own event handlers, the other window will fire the same events, any idea how to use handlers in first window to handle events in second window ?

Comment: Derive both windows from a common base class that handles the events?

Comment: How !!, they're already derived from `System.Windows.Window`

Comment: You aren't limited to a single level of inheritance. [`System.Windows.Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) already has a deeply-nested inheritance hierarchy, as shown on the linked documentation page. Your base class derives from `System.Windows.Window`, then your two windows derive from the base class. Standard OO design.

Comment: Where are those windows contained?

Comment: Two windows are located in the same namespace,and they're like this! : `public partial class Window1 : Window` and `public partial class Window2 : Window` , `window1` contains event handlers for some events, the same events will be fired in `window2`, how to make event handlers in `window1` handle the same events in `window2` with same code implementation

Comment: If you could put those two windows inside a (main) window, you'd easily solve your issue!

Comment: @Natxo ok, but how ?!

Comment: Short of creating an event aggregator, which seems overkill, I think @CodyGray has the best solution of creating a base class. Classes can only inherit from one class (but multiple interfaces) in C# but that's not a problem. Create a `CustomWindow : Window` class with all your event handlers. Then `Window1` and `"Window2` are derived from `CustomWindow`, not `Window` (i.e. `public partial class Window1 : CustomWindow`).

Comment: Howa, a window can contain other windows! Thats how. Anyway, it's probably more elegant to create subclass of Window as others are suggesting.

Comment: @keyboardP thank you very much, really helped !, i also found this helpful article on how to implement what u've suggest http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx

Comment: @Howa - You're welcome. Wow it seems that article was written just for this question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Cody Gray , @keyboardP and to this useful article http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate the answer:

**first step** add a new subclass :

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication
{
   public class Subclass : Window
   {
    //Event handlers,functions or any potential reused code
   }
}
```

**Second step:** go to window1.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
     public partial class Window1 : Subclass
     {
       public Window1()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }
     }
}
```

**Third step**: change the Xaml code for window1 as below:

```
<src:Subclass 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="525">
 </src:Subclass>
```

**Finally** do 2nd & 3rd steps for window2

Answer (score 0):

A simple sample of what i was proposing in first place:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Window Loaded="Window_Loaded"/>
        <Window Loaded="Window_Loaded"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Look how both windows share the event handler:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Whatever
    }
}
```

At this point you should ask yourself if you really needed two windows, or any other container control could be enough.

Comment: <Window> can only be used as root.